# How can i prevent access indexes in browser in lamp server on ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: apache2

Hey guys i want to prevent access to my root directory through indexes using the browser. when forexample i type http://172.16.19.10:9554/ in the url, it displays website folders which i dont want.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have two options.  The first being adjusting your site configuration, the second is adding an `.htaccess` to the directory root.

I would suggest editing your site configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.  When you find the configuration for the site you're trying to adjust, open it up and look for `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`.  If you find that line, you can simply add a '-' to `-Indexes`.

**Sample**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Or you can create an .htaccess file within the root directory for your site.  That file can contain just `Options -Indexes`.

The first method is preferred as you may need to adjust your site configuration to `AllowOverride All` to use the .htaccess.